# How to retrieve the third most recent date grouped another column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

**EDIT**: I am using SQL Server 2005

So here's a tricky one.  For audit purposes, we need to make 3 attempts to contact a customer.  We can make more than 3 attempts to go above and beyond, but audit purposes I need to retrieve the date of the third most recent attempt for each customer.

In most cases, you just need the most recent period, so you can do something like..

```
SELECT CustID,MAX(AttemptDate) FROM Attempts GROUP BY CustID
```

.. but that obviously won't work in this scenario.

Say I have a table of attempts that occur which are tied to a customer.

```
CustID    AttemptDate
123       2014-01-02
123       2014-01-05
123       2014-01-06 * retrieve this one
123       2014-01-07
123       2014-01-10
555       2014-02-01
555       2014-02-03
555       2014-02-07 * retrieve this one
555       2014-02-12
555       2014-02-20
```

Output:

```
CustID    AttemptDate
123       2014-01-06
555       2014-02-07
```

Any tips for pulling this off?

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH t AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY AttemptDate DESC) AS nth_most_recent
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE nth_most_recent = 3
```

Comment: I failed to mention I am stuck with SQL Server 2005.  This is giving me errors, and I'm not entirely sure which part is causing it.  I'm guessing incompatibility.  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. / Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'."

Comment: @user1003916 That's because the syntax used in this answer is wrong. It should be `PARTITION BY`, not `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Anon I'm still getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'."  I used that code verbatim to test this

Comment: @user1003916 Look, do you have some more code **previous** to adding this answer?, try adding a semmicolon to the begining: `;WITH t AS(`

Comment: @user1003916 if a statement begins with the keyword `WITH` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175972%28v=sql.90%29.aspx , then the previous statement needs to be properly terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @Lamak - I try this question too. Can you please tell me if my answer is a okay ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev No, it's not, that will return every 3rd row per custId

Answer (score 1):

The [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function is your friend here:

```
  WITH cte (CustId, AttemptDate, AttemptNumber) AS (
    SELECT 
      CustId,
      AttemptDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY AttemptDate DESC) AS AttemptNumber
    FROM Attempts
  )
  SELECT 
    CustId,
    AttemptDate
  FROM cte
  WHERE AttemptNumber = 3
```

Alternatively, if the common table expression syntax is causing problems, you could use a subquery:

```
  SELECT
    CustId,
    AttemptDate
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      CustId,
      AttemptDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY AttemptDate DESC) AS AttemptNumber
    FROM Attempts
  ) sq
  WHERE AttemptNumber = 3
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to state the reasons for the downvote?

Comment: It wasn't me, but you need to order by attempdate DESC

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe As with Anon's sample - I am getting an error.  Might it be that I'm on sql server 2005? "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'."

Comment: @user1003916 Again, as I said in the previous comment, did you try adding a semmicolon?: `;WITH cte AS ( `?

Comment: I don't recall whether SQL Server 2005 required column names in the CTEs. I've updated my answer to include them.

Comment: I've also added a CTE-free version of the solution. The important part, after all, is the `ROW_NUMBER` ...